# Make the notification drawer animation faster

Tags: notifications, root-access, custom-roms, customization

I'm running a SlimKat ROM on Sony Xperia Z Ultra. For me the open animation of the notification drawer is too slow. Is there any way to make it faster or disable at all?

Answer (score -1):

There is a very simple solution to your this wish.Just simply head over to your settings .
After headed, go to DEVELOPER OPTIONS. If you do not have the DEVELOPER OPTIONS then simply go to ABOUT PHONE>BUILD NUMBER and tap the BUILD NUMBER  several times until you see a message that now you are a developer or something like that. Now go to DEVELOPER OPTIONS and Enable it. Now scroll down until you see WINDOW ANIMATION SCALE. Tap it and choose the time you want. You can even disable it(set it to off. Do the same to TRANSITION ANIMATION SCALE and to ANIMATOR DURATION SCALE. You can even set different scale to different animations. And VOILA there you GO!! Hope it helped ;) :D